# How to intersect dataframe based on column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data1

```
    BAKUNG  BALATAK    BARUGA  BERINGIN CEMERLANG
1 5.397762 4.4421650 1.1371410 0.1915185 1.2023105
2 4.551889 1.1710558 0.6596748 2.2443573 5.5094816
3 9.290642 1.9318098 0.3717321 0.7481191 2.3554114
4 1.758246 1.6478570 1.1930006 0.7687339 1.5786976
5 2.497720 0.5127110 0.3331624 0.3225225 0.7541041
6 3.080921 0.6563498 1.8712953 1.0959114 1.1883456
```

and data2

```
             BAKUNG           BALATAK   CEMERLANG
1              <NA>              <NA>        <NA>
2              <NA>                 2        <NA>
3                14                 6        <NA>
4                17              <NA>           1
5              <NA>              <NA>        <NA>
6              <NA>              <NA>        <NA>
  AMPANA TETE AMPIBABO
1        <NA>     <NA>
2        <NA>     <NA>
3        <NA>     <NA>
4        <NA>     <NA>
5        <NA>     <NA>
6        <NA>     <NA>
```

I want to find data station from data1 and data2 with the same station name. Here data I want to get

```
    BAKUNG_data1 BAKUNG_data2 BALATAK_data1 BALATAK_data2
 1       5.397762           NA     4.4421650            NA
 2       4.551889           NA     1.1710558             2
 3       9.290642           14     1.9318098             6
 4       1.758246           17     1.6478570            NA
 5       2.497720           NA     0.5127110            NA
 6       3.080921           NA     0.6563498            NA
```

I tried

```
abc <- merge(data1,data2, by = intersect(names(data1), names(data2)))
```

but I got nothing, is there any way to solve it?

Comment: hi @RonakShah
I just tried various simulations about the solution you gave, initially there were some simulations that failed, but then I tried to match the way you gave it and it worked,
sorry for what I did before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to get data in long format and then do the join, finally getting the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)

inner_join(data1 %>% 
            mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
            pivot_longer(cols = -row, values_to = "data1"),
           data2 %>% 
            mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
            pivot_longer(cols = -row, values_to = "data2"), 
           by = c('name', 'row')) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = starts_with('data')) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to change the column names

```
tmp=intersect(names(data1), names(data2))
colnames(data1)=paste0(colnames(data1),"_data1")
colnames(data2)=paste0(colnames(data2),"_data2")
cbind(data1[grepl(paste0("^",tmp,".*",collapse="|"),colnames(data1))],
      data2[grepl(paste0("^",tmp,".*",collapse="|"),colnames(data2))])

  BAKUNG_data1 BALATAK_data1 CEMERLANG_data1 BAKUNG_data2 BALATAK_data2 CEMERLANG_data2
1     5.397762     4.4421650       1.2023105         <NA>          <NA>            <NA>
2     4.551889     1.1710558       5.5094816         <NA>             2            <NA>
3     9.290642     1.9318098       2.3554114           14             6            <NA>
4     1.758246     1.6478570       1.5786976           17          <NA>               1
5     2.497720     0.5127110       0.7541041         <NA>          <NA>            <NA>
6     3.080921     0.6563498       1.1883456         <NA>          <NA>            <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a "INDEX" column to perform the join on.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse) 

data1 <- read.table(textConnection("
BAKUNG  BALATAK    BARUGA  BERINGIN CEMERLANG
5.397762 4.4421650 1.1371410 0.1915185 1.2023105
4.551889 1.1710558 0.6596748 2.2443573 5.5094816
9.290642 1.9318098 0.3717321 0.7481191 2.3554114
1.758246 1.6478570 1.1930006 0.7687339 1.5786976
2.497720 0.5127110 0.3331624 0.3225225 0.7541041
3.080921 0.6563498 1.8712953 1.0959114 1.1883456"), header = TRUE, na.strings = "<NA>")

data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
data1 <- data1 %>% mutate(INDEX = row_number())

data2 <- read.table(textConnection("
BAKUNG BALATAK CEMERLANG AMPANA_TETE AMPIBABO
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
<NA> 2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
14 6 <NA> <NA> <NA>
17 <NA> 1 <NA> <NA>
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>"), header = TRUE, na.strings = "<NA>")

data2 <- as.data.frame(data2)
data2 <- data2 %>% mutate(INDEX = row_number())

data3 <- inner_join(data1, data2, by = c("INDEX", "INDEX"), suffix = c("_data1", "_data2"))
data3 <- data3 %>% select(contains("data"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Store a vector of the names of vectors common to both dataframes: 

common_cols <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))

# Column bind the dataframes: 

df3 <- cbind(setNames(df1[,common_cols], paste0(common_cols, "_data1")), 
      setNames(df2[,common_cols],  paste0(common_cols, "_data2")))

# Order the dataframe as required

df3_ordered <- df3[,sort(names(df3))]
```

Data:

```
df1 <-
  structure(
    list(
      BAKUNG = c(5.397762, 4.551889, 9.290642,
                 1.758246, 2.49772, 3.080921),
      BALATAK = c(4.442165, 1.1710558,
                  1.9318098, 1.647857, 0.512711, 0.6563498),
      BARUGA = c(1.137141,
                 0.6596748, 0.3717321, 1.1930006, 0.3331624, 1.8712953),
      BERINGIN = c(
        0.1915185,
        2.2443573,
        0.7481191,
        0.7687339,
        0.3225225,
        1.0959114
      ),
      CEMERLANG = c(
        1.2023105,
        5.5094816,
        2.3554114,
        1.5786976,
        0.7541041,
        1.1883456
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-6L)
  )

df2 <-
  structure(
    list(
      BAKUNG = c("<NA>", "<NA>", "14", "17",
                 "<NA>", "<NA>"),
      BALATAK = c("<NA>", "2", "6", "<NA>", "<NA>",
                  "<NA>"),
      CEMERLANG = c("<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "1", "<NA>", "<NA>")
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-6L)
  )
```